# Topology on power set defined by indicator functions

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory, reference-request

I have recently encountered some topological construction on sub-collection of the power set, and was wondering whether there was a topology defined as follows:

Let $X$ be a non-empty set, and let $\mathcal{C}(X)\subseteq 2^X$ be a collection of subsets of $X$. I want to define a topology on $\mathcal{C}(X)$ such that a net $\{ S_\alpha \}\subseteq \mathcal{C}(X)$ converges to $S\in \mathcal{C}(X)$ iff $\chi_{S_\alpha}\to \chi_S$ pointwise. In essence I want to define a topology on $\mathcal{C}(X)$ such that the limit will coincide with the set thoertic limit.

Is this a studied structure or one which people have discussed at some point?

I'm asking because I was wondering whether topologies on subsets of the power set, such as hit and miss topologies, agree with set thoertic limits, but I have just recently been introduced to such notions.

---

Edit:

Lately I've encountered the notion of Kuratowski convergence, which is defined similarly to $\overline{\lim} A_n$ and $\underline{\lim} A_n$. Given a sequence of sets $A_n$ in $X$, the Kuratowski limit inferior is defined by

$$ \underset{n\to \infty}{Li}A_n:=\{ x \in X: \;  \text{for all open } U\ni x, \; U\cap A_n\neq \emptyset \; \text{for } n \; \text{large enough}    \}, $$

and the Kuratowski limit superior is defined by

$$ \underset{n\to \infty}{Ls}A_n:=\{ x \in X: \;  \text{for all open } U\ni x, \; U\cap A_n\neq \emptyset \; \text{for infinitely many } n     \}. $$

I think a sructure for which $\underset{n\to \infty}{Li}A_n= \underline{\lim} A_n$ and $\underset{n\to \infty}{Ls}A_n =\overline{A_n} $, would give the desired topology.

Comment: Take the subspace topology of the product topology on $\{0,1\}^{X}$.

Comment: @DanielFischer So using this identification, can I determine whether another topology on the space notion of limits correspond with the set-thoertic one? For example by saying that the other topology is finer?

Comment: Since you're considering nets and not just sequences, convergence determines the topology. The subspace topology on $\mathcal{C}(X)$ (via the identification of subsets of $X$ with their characteristic function) is the only topology in which a net converges iff the net of characteristic functions converges pointwise. If you consider only sequences of sets, I'm not sure whether it's the only one.